# Display JqGrid Column modal as Date and Hyper Link shows NAN/NAN/NAN

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have dynamic JQGrid in which one of the column is Date column. I get the data from feeds which has the URL and Date.

I need to develop column model for "**Date column**" in such a way that it shows the Date and Hyper link. But unfortunately the data get displayed as NAN/NAN/NAN (This could be because it is treating the entire string - `<a>...</a>` as date rather than "20/8/2016"). Can any one please let me know how can I display the Date here in correct text rather than NAN??

**Note:** I Should even make sure that Sorting of the date is maintained

Sample Code Snippet that is **working** - When there is **no Anchor tag** & **not working** - when there is a **Anchor tag**. However irrespective of anchor tag this works always when the column modal is of type text - in other words this happens only for date column and not for other columns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var data = [{ 'Date': "<a href=https://google.com target=_blank style=text-decoration:underline;>20/8/2016</a>" },
                 { 'Date': "<a href=https://google.com target=_blank style=text-decoration:underline;>21/8/2016</a>" },
                 { 'Date': "<a href=https://google.com target=_blank style=text-decoration:underline;>22/8/2016</a>" },
                 { 'Date': "2016-08-09T06:11:14.907Z" }, { 'Date': "2016-08-10T06:11:14.907Z" }
            ]
            $("#grid").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                datastr: data,
                colNames: ["Date"],
                colModel: [{ name: 'Date', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {newformat:'n/j/Y'} }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="grid"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `formatter: 'date'` expect the input data in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) by default. You can't use HTML fragments instead. If you need to format dates as links (`<a>`) then you can use ISO 8601 in the input data, but to use [custom formater](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) to format the data as the links. Please include in all questions about jqGrid which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS or an ald jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Answer (score 1):

jqgrid afterinsertrow use

```
var data = [{ 'Date': "20/8/2016" },
      { 'Date': "20/8/2016" },
      { 'Date': "20/8/2016" },
      { 'Date': "2016-08-09T06:11:14.907Z" }, 
      { 'Date': "2016-08-10T06:11:14.907Z" }
 ]
 $("#grid").jqGrid({
     datatype: 'jsonstring',
     datastr: data,
     colNames: ["Date"],
     colModel: [{ name: 'Date', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {newformat:'n/j/Y'} }],
     **afterInsertRow : function(rowid, aData){
         if(rowid == 1){
             $("#grid").jqGrid('setCell' ,rowid, 'Date', "<a href=https://google.com target=_blank style=text-decoration:underline;>"+aData.Date+"</a>", {});
         }
     }**
 });
```

Comment: is there a more generic way. This will start adding hyperlink to all the cells if i remove the if condition. I guess i need to find if its a date column and having the url then make the if condition to true. Is there a way to Identity what type of column it is and dose this has the hyperlink?

Answer (score 0):

```
colModel: [{ name: 'Date', sorttype: 'date',
             formatter:function(cellvalue, options, rowObject)                {
               var dt=new Date(cellvalue);
               if(dt=='Invalid Date')return cellvalue;//chrome
               var y=dt.getFullYear();
               var m=dt.getMonth()+1<10?'0'+(dt.getMonth()+1):dt.getMonth()+1;
               var d=dt.getDate()<10:'0'+dt.getDate():dt.getDate();
               return y+'-'+m+'-'+d;
             }
               }]
```

Comment: I can't consider this because it messes up with format of the date that needs to be displayed. no Sorting is also not working

Comment: if you want the list to be sorted correctly,the items must have a same format

Comment: your solution is working to me but it is displaying the format in ISO where as i have given the date to display in 'n/j/Y'. Even sorting is not working properly

Comment: what is the new format like?I have no idea about 'n/j/Y'.